# F#: Flattening a sequence of sequences into a single Seq

Tags: f#, f#-scripting

I am trying to build a single sequence that contains the contents of multiple files so that it can be sorted and then passed to a graphing component. However I am stuck trying to fold the contents of each file together. The pseudo code below wont compile but hopefully will show the intention of what I am trying to achieve.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

```
open System.IO 

let FileEnumerator filename = seq { 
        use sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(filename)
           while not sr.EndOfStream do 
           let line = sr.ReadLine()
            yield line 
}

let files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"D:\test_Data\","*.csv",SearchOption.AllDirectories)

let res =
   files 
        |> Seq.fold(fun x item -> 
        let lines =  FileEnumerator(item)
        let sq = Seq.concat x ; lines
        sq
    ) seq<string>

printfn "%A" res
```

Comment: are you looking for Seq.collect http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340468.aspx ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are essentially trying to reimplement [Files.Readlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx), which returns the file contents as `seq<string>`.  This can then be concatenated with Seq.concat:

```
let res = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"D:\test_Data","*.csv",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
          |> Seq.map File.ReadLines 
          |> Seq.concat
```

Answer (score 4):

To fix the problem in your original approach, you need to use `Seq.append` instead of `Seq.concat`. The initial value for `fold` should be an empty sequence, which can be written as `Seq.empty`:

```
let res = 
   files |> Seq.fold(fun x item ->  
        let lines =  FileEnumerator(item) 
        let sq = Seq.append x lines 
        sq ) Seq.empty
```

If you wanted to use `Seq.concat`, you'd have to write `Seq.concat [x; lines]`, because `concat` expects a sequence of sequences to be concatenated. On the other hand, `append` simply takes two sequences, so it is easier to use here.

Another (simpler) way to concatenate all the lines is to use `yield!` in sequence expressions:

```
let res = 
  seq { for item in files do
          yield! FileEnumerator(item) }
```

This creates a sequence by iterating over all the files and adding all lines from the files (in order) to the resulting sequence. The `yield!` construct adds all elements of the sequenece to the result.